# reset formControl to initialvalues does not keep disabled

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a formGroup with some fields disabled by default, I want to keep this disabled when reset the form, but reset only set the value to  '':

```
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
    control: new FormControl({
      value: '',
      disabled: true
    }, {
      validators: [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(3)
      ],
      updateOn: 'blur'
    })
  });

  //other logic that enables the field...

  this.formGroup.get('control').reset();
```

this code cleans the input but it is not disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `this.formGroup.get('control').reset({value: '', disabled: true });`
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset